# CVXPY Constraint reformulation

Tags: normed-spaces, cvxpy

If $\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}$ can be written as `cp.norm(cp.hstack([1, $x$]), 2)` instead of `cp.sqrt(1 + cp.square($x$))`, what is the correct way of writing

\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{\gamma_{u}\sum_{j\in \mathcal{L}\backslash\lbrace l\rbrace}\left(h_{j,u}p_{j}\right)^{{2}} + \sigma_{u}^{{2}}},
\end{equation}

in CVXPY in order for it to follow the DCP rules? I had simply written it as cp.norm($\gamma_u$ * (cp.square($hp_{j1}$) + cp.square($hp_{j2}$) + ... + cp.square($hp_\mathcal{L}$)) + cp.square($\sigma_u$)). I was wondering if this is correct or I need to follow the conversion of stacticking as done in the example above to turn my equation into a vector?

Comment: Your form is not correct because you combine cp.norm with cp.square, whereas your function is *cp.sqrt* and cp.square. You need to construct a vector and use cp.norm.

Comment: @LinAlg, basically, I should drop the cp.square completely? In a case where we have sqrt(sum(square(x)), why do we directly take the norm without vectorising? Because it is just one element without any other term that modifies it??

Comment: we directly take the norm because the CVX ruleset does not recognize sqrt(sum(square(x))) as a convex function

Comment: @LinAlg So, for my problem above I should have cp.norm(cp.hstack([$\gamma_u$ * ($hp_{j1}$ + ... + $hp_{\mathcal{L}}$) , $\sigma_u$]))? Is this the equivalent form?

Comment: No, that is not the equivalent form; norm takes each of the elements of the vector, squares it, and takes the sum.

Comment: Please do not mix MathJax with Python. Pick one